# Update the geometry after modifying mesh in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Upon loading a Ply file with `PLYLoader`, I modify the mesh a little bit so it looks better:

```
loader.load(
  filename,
  function ( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x0055ff } );
    geometry.dynamic = true;
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
    mesh.rotation.set(angleX, 0, 0);
    mesh.scale.set( sFactor, sFactor, sFactor );
    //mesh.updateMatrix();
    //mesh.geometry.applyMatrix( mesh.matrix );
    //mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    scene.add( mesh );
});
```

This renders the mesh perfectly, but later on I need to access the vertices with the new values. I know that you have to update also the geometry, but I don't find the correct combination.

I have tried setting the geometry to "dynamic" and then applying the `mesh.matrix`, as shown in the commented code. That makes the mesh render incorrectly (it's like it applied twice the transformation).

I'm doing something wrong but I don't find what. Does someone know how can update the geometry?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531109/three-js-vertices-does-not-update/24536525#24536525

Comment: That's what I do and what it's not working for me, see the commented code.

Comment: I see. All you need to do is construct your desired matrix transform, and call geometry.applyMatrix( myMatrixTransform ). Do not modify the mesh's matrix.

Comment: Also you can rotate, scale and translate your geometry before applying it to the mesh. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/enkdv7fk/)

Comment: Hi, I got it working using geometry.applyMatrix( myMatrixTransform ), but after that I need to reset the mesh position, rotation and scale. I don't understand why, but it works now and I moved on :)